# How does the garbage collector determine whether an object is garbage?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

How does the garbage collector determine whether an object is garbage? Does it refer to the stack to check the references to the space allocated in the heap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It employs a [mark and sweep algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). The simplified version: It starts out by considering all objects to be eligible for collection. It then scans for roots to objects. Any rooted object are then marked as in use. Following that all remaining objects are considered garbage. There's an excellent description of the details in [CLR via C#](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2009/06/17/clr-via-c-3rd-edition.aspx) by Jeffrey Richter.

Comment: got the book and read it. thanks a lot. it is very clear now.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/) article by A. Hunter explains it all pretty good.

In short, the GC follows references to find all unreachable objects. An object refers to another object if it or any of its superclasses contains a field with the other object.

To achieve this, the GC keeps track of four types of root objects called *GC roots*. The most common root type is all variables created on the stack (as you guessed). Other root types are statics, interop-related and objects with a finalizer method.

So yes, the GC refers to the stack in most cases.

Comment: A minor correction - all variables created on the stack is misleading, "A local variable in a method that is currently running is considered to be a GC root. The objects referenced by these variables can always be accessed immediately by the method they are declared in, and so they must be kept around. The lifetime of these roots can depend on the way the program was built. In debug builds, a local variable lasts for as long as the method is on the stack." Ref. - http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to read some literature about this: [Java theory and practice: Garbage collection and performance](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp01274.html) and [Garbage Collector Basics and Performance Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx).